# Keeping a console application alive in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, console-application, azure-service-fabric, guest-executable

Are there any established patterns for keeping console applications alive when hosted as guest executables in Service Fabric?

Adding a `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)` after I've subscribed to Service Bus or similar feels like a bit of a hack to me. Other approaches I've seen use Console.ReadKey(), but, again, this feels like a hack.

Comment: What's hacky about it?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)` is what all service/actor hosts do to prevents process from terminating. Look at _Program.Main_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)` appears to be what's recommended by Microsoft according to their Azure Service Fabric samples in GitHub:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/src/GettingStartedApplication/ActorBackendService/Program.cs

Answer (score 1):

Console.ReadKey() is perfectly fine. You can Write a message before like

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

so the user knows how to end the application.